# RecyclerView Scrolling slow after returning from activity

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have an activity that has a RecyclerView with cardViews. This recyclerView is populated by a service response. The first time I enter to the activity, the recyclerView scroll down and up normal, with normal speed. If I tap on one of the cardView, there is an Intent to go to an activity detail of this card. If I come back to the recyclerView (by tapping the back button), the scroll down and up of the recyclerView is slower, y if I enter again to the detail, and come back, the scroll is slower than the last time and so on.

This is the adapter code:

```
public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private FirebaseFirestore db;
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<Cupon> mList;
    private CountryUser cu;

    public CardAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Cupon> list, FirebaseFirestore db, CountryUser cu) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mList = list;
        this.db = db;
        this.cu = cu;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.rv_card_items, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        viewHolder.bind(mList.get(i));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return mList.get(position).hashCode(); //id()
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView titulo;
        private TextView subtitulo;
        private TextView precioReal;
        private TextView precioDesc;
        private ImageView imagen;
        private ImageView imgComercio;
        private ImageButton fav;
        private CardView cardView;

        private ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            titulo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_titulo);
            subtitulo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_subtitulo);
            precioReal = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_precioReal);
            precioDesc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_precioDesc);
            imagen = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageview_imagenCupon);
            imgComercio = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_comercio);
            cardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
            fav = itemView.findViewById(R.id.fav);
        }

        private void bind(Cupon cardItem){

            favorite(Objects.requireNonNull(cardItem.getIdCategoria()));

            titulo.setText(cardItem.getTitulo());
            subtitulo.setText(cardItem.getSubtitulo());
            precioReal.setText(cardItem.getPrecioReal());
            precioDesc.setText(cardItem.getPrecioDesc());

            if (imagen != null) {
                Picasso.get()
                        .load(cardItem.getImagenCupon())
                        .fit()
                        .centerCrop()
                        .error(R.drawable.notfound)
                        .into(imagen);
            }

            if (imgComercio != null){
                Picasso.get()
                        .load(cardItem.getImagenComercio())
                        .fit()
                        .centerInside()
                        .error(R.drawable.notfound)
                        .into(imgComercio);
            }

            fav.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                Animation animScale = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.scale_fav);
                v.startAnimation(animScale);
                addFav(cardItem.getIdCategoria());
            });

            cardView.setOnClickListener(v -> mContext.startActivity(DetalleCuponActivity.getIntent(mContext, cardItem.getIdCategoria(), "0")));
        }

        private void favorite(String id) {
            String favorito = "0";
            db.collection("Favorito")
                    .whereEqualTo("idUsuario", Fn.Companion.getUserUID())
                    .whereEqualTo("idCupon", id)
                    .whereEqualTo("estado", favorito)
                    .get()
                    .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            if (Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult()).isEmpty()) {
                                fav.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_favorito);
                            } else {
                                Animation animScale = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.scale_fav);
                                fav.startAnimation(animScale);
                                fav.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_corazon);
                            }
                        } else Log.d("ERROR", "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                    });
        }

        private void addFav(final String id) {
            String favorito = "0";
            db.collection("Favorito")
                    .whereEqualTo("idUsuario", Fn.Companion.getUserUID())
                    .whereEqualTo("idCupon", id)
                    .whereEqualTo("estado", favorito)
                    .get()
                    .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            if (Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult()).isEmpty()) {
                                fav.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_corazon);

                                String pais = cu.getAbr();

                                Map<String, Object> newFav = new HashMap<>();
                                newFav.put("idUsuario", Fn.Companion.getUserUID());
                                newFav.put("idCupon", id);
                                newFav.put("fecha", new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
                                newFav.put("estado", "0");
                                newFav.put("tipo", "c");
                                newFav.put("pais", pais);

                                db.collection("Favorito")
                                        .add(newFav)
                                        .addOnFailureListener(e -> fav.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_favorito));
                            } else {
                                fav.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_favorito);
                                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                    DocumentReference ref = db.collection("Favorito").document(document.getId());
                                    ref.update("estado", "1")
                                            .addOnFailureListener(e -> fav.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_corazon));
                                }
                            }
                        } else Log.d("ERROR", "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                    });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetachedFromRecyclerView(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onDetachedFromRecyclerView(recyclerView);
        RoomDataBase.destroyInstance();
        mContext = null;
        cu = null;
    }

    public void setFilter(ArrayList<Cupon> newCupon) {
        mList = new ArrayList<>();
        mList.addAll(newCupon);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

And this is the way I setup the recyclerView:

```
PreCachingLayoutManagerHelper rvLiLayoutManager = new PreCachingLayoutManagerHelper(this);
            rvLiLayoutManager.setOrientation(androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
rvLiLayoutManager.setExtraLayoutSpace(metrics.heightPixels * 3);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(rvLiLayoutManager);

cardAdapter = new CardAdapter(mContext, cardList, FirebaseFirestore.getInstance(),Fn.Companion.getUserSession());
recyclerView.setAdapter(cardAdapter);
```

And this is the view:
[BusquedaActivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0Hwj.jpg)

Thank you so much for your help.

EDIT: this is the whole activity code.

```
public class BusquedaActivity extends BaseActivity implements CardAdapter.CardAdapterCallback {

    public final static String OPCIONID = "opcionid";
    public final static String CATEGORYNAME = "categoryiname";
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
    private Dialog dialog;
    private LinearLayout emptytId;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ArrayList<Cupon> cardList;
    private ArrayList<VipCoupon> dataList;
    private CardAdapter cardAdapter;
    private VipCouponAdapter vipCouponAdapter;
    private CardView commerceCoupon;
    private CardView vipCoupon;
    private final boolean fav = false;
    // Modification Custom Search Adapter
    private SearchView searchView;
    private CustomSearchAdapter mAdapter;
    private TextView generalCardText;
    private TextView vipCardText;
    private boolean activeVIP = false;

    public static Intent getIntent(Context context, String opcion, String name) {
        return new Intent(context, BusquedaActivity.class)
                .putExtra(OPCIONID, opcion)
                .putExtra(CATEGORYNAME, name);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_busqueda);

        // Toolbar
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        // Views
        swipeRefreshLayout = findViewById(R.id.swipe);
        commerceCoupon = findViewById(R.id.commerceCoupon);
        vipCoupon = findViewById(R.id.vipCoupon);
        generalCardText = findViewById(R.id.general);
        vipCardText = findViewById(R.id.vip);
        emptytId = findViewById(R.id.emptytId);
        dialog = new Dialog(BusquedaActivity.this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_loader);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv);

        // RecyclerView
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
        recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(Global.PAGE_SIZE * 2);
        recyclerView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        recyclerView.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);

        PreCachingLayoutManagerHelper rvLiLayoutManager = new PreCachingLayoutManagerHelper(this);
        rvLiLayoutManager.setOrientation(androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        rvLiLayoutManager.setExtraLayoutSpace(metrics.heightPixels * 3);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(rvLiLayoutManager);

        // Adapter
        cardList = new ArrayList<>();
        dataList = new ArrayList<>();
        cardAdapter = new CardAdapter(this, cardList, FirebaseFirestore.getInstance(), this);
        cardAdapter.setHasStableIds(true);
        vipCouponAdapter = new VipCouponAdapter(this, dataList);
        vipCouponAdapter.setHasStableIds(true);

        TextView titulo = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
        titulo.setText(Objects.requireNonNull(getIntent().getExtras()).getString(CATEGORYNAME));

        Objects.requireNonNull(dialog.getWindow()).setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.show();

        dialog.setOnCancelListener(dialog -> {
            finish();
            dialog.dismiss();
        });

        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(() -> {
            if (activeVIP) {
                emptytId.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                commerceCoupon.setEnabled(true);
                vipCoupon.setEnabled(false);
                generalCardText.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.loader));
                vipCardText.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryLigth));
                recyclerView.setAdapter(vipCouponAdapter);
                cardList.clear();
                dataList.clear();
                if (Objects.equals(Objects.requireNonNull(getIntent().getExtras()).getString(OPCIONID), "2")) {
                    aprovechaYaVIP();
                } else if (Objects.equals(Objects.requireNonNull(getIntent().getExtras()).getString(OPCIONID), "3")) {
                    loNuevoVIP();
                } else if (Objects.equals(Objects.requireNonNull(getIntent().getExtras()).getString(OPCIONID), "4")) {
                    mejoresDescuentosVIP();
                }
            } else {
                emptytId.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                commerceCoupon.setEnabled(false);
                vipCoupon.setEnabled(true);
                generalCardText.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryLigth));
                vipCardText.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.loader));
                recyclerView.setAdapter(cardAdapter);
                cardList.clear();
                dataList.clear();
                if (Objects.equals(Objects.requireNonNull(getIntent().getExtras()).getString(OPCIONID), "2")) {
                    aprovechaYa();
                } else if (Objects.equals(Objects.requireNonNull(getIntent().getExtras()).getString(OPCIONID), "3")) {
                    loNuevo();
                } else if (Objects.equals(Objects.requireNonNull(getIntent().getExtras()).getString(OPCIONID), "4")) {
                    mejoresDescuentos();
                }
            }
        });

        commerceCoupon.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            activeVIP = false;
            emptytId.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            commerceCoupon.setEnabled(false);
            vipCoupon.setEnabled(true);
            generalCardText.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryLigth));
            vipCardText.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.loader));
            recyclerView.setAdapter(cardAdapter);
            cardList.clear();
            dataList.clear();
            if (Objects.equals(Objects.requireNonNull(getIntent().getExtras()).getString(OPCIONID), "2")) {
                aprovechaYa();
            } else if (Objects.equals(Objects.requireNonNull(getIntent().getExtras()).getString(OPCIONID), "3")) {
                loNuevo();
            } else if (Objects.equals(Objects.requireNonNull(getIntent().getExtras()).getString(OPCIONID), "4")) {
                mejoresDescuentos();
            }
        });

        vipCoupon.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            activeVIP = true;
            emptytId.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            commerceCoupon.setEnabled(true);
            vipCoupon.setEnabled(false);
            generalCardText.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.loader));
            vipCardText.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryLigth));
            recyclerView.setAdapter(vipCouponAdapter);
            cardList.clear();
            dataList.clear();
            if (Objects.equals(Objects.requireNonNull(getIntent().getExtras()).getString(OPCIONID), "2")) {
                aprovechaYaVIP();
            } else if (Objects.equals(Objects.requireNonNull(getIntent().getExtras()).getString(OPCIONID), "3")) {
                loNuevoVIP();
            } else if (Objects.equals(Objects.requireNonNull(getIntent().getExtras()).getString(OPCIONID), "4")) {
                mejoresDescuentosVIP();
            }
        });

        mAdapter = new CustomSearchAdapter(this, null);

        // Show Data
        initData();
    }

@Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        onBackPressed();
        this.finish();
        return super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        recyclerView.setAdapter(null);
        searchView = null;
        super.onDestroy();
    }

private void initData() {
        activeVIP = false;
        emptytId.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        commerceCoupon.setEnabled(false);
        vipCoupon.setEnabled(true);
        generalCardText.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryLigth));
        vipCardText.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.loader));
        cardList.clear();
        dataList.clear();
        if (Objects.equals(Objects.requireNonNull(getIntent().getExtras()).getString(OPCIONID), "2")) {
            aprovechaYa();
        } else if (Objects.equals(Objects.requireNonNull(getIntent().getExtras()).getString(OPCIONID), "3")) {
            loNuevo();
        } else if (Objects.equals(Objects.requireNonNull(getIntent().getExtras()).getString(OPCIONID), "4")) {
            mejoresDescuentos();
        }
    }

private void mejoresDescuentos() {
        Call<ArrayList<Cupon>> mejor = getRetrofit().create(Api.class).getMejores(Fn.Companion.getUserCountry());

        mejor.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<Cupon>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ArrayList<Cupon>> call, @NonNull Response<ArrayList<Cupon>> response) {
                if (response.code() == 200) {
                    ArrayList<Cupon> ap = response.body();
                    if (Objects.requireNonNull(ap).isEmpty()) {
                        showEmptyLayout(true);
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    } else {
                        showEmptyLayout(false);
                        DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("###,###.00");
                        String m = Fn.Companion.getUserSession().getMoneda();
                        for (Cupon c : Objects.requireNonNull(ap)) {
                            String realPrice = "null";
                            String descPrice = "null";
                            String descuentoCode;
                            if (c.getFbCodeType() == null || c.getFbCodeType().equals("")) {
                                descuentoCode = "1";
                            } else {
                                descuentoCode = c.getFbCodeType();
                            }

                            if (descuentoCode == null || descuentoCode.equals("") || descuentoCode.equals("1")) {
                                double real = Double.parseDouble(c.getPrecioReal());
                                realPrice = String.valueOf(Html.fromHtml("<strike>" + m + " " + format.format(real) + "</strike>"));
                                double descuento = Double.parseDouble(c.getPrecioDesc());
                                descPrice = m + " " + format.format(descuento);
                            } else if (descuentoCode.equals("2")) {
                                realPrice = "";
                                double descuento = Double.parseDouble(c.getPrecioDesc());
                                descPrice = format.format(descuento) + " %";
                            } else if (descuentoCode.equals("3")) {
                                realPrice = "";
                                double descuento = Double.parseDouble(c.getPrecioDesc());
                                descPrice = m + " " + format.format(descuento);
                            }

                            cardList.add(new Cupon(c.getIdCategoria(), c.getTitulo(), c.getSubtitulo(), descPrice, realPrice, c.getDescripcion(), c.getTyc(), c.getCantCanje(), c.getCantCanjeUSER(), c.getFechaInicio(), c.getFechaFin(), c.getImagenCupon(), c.getImagenComercio(), c.getNombreComercio(), c.getIdComercio(), c.getWhatsapp(), c.getInstagram(), c.getFacebook(), c.getPais(), descuentoCode,fav));
                        }
                        cardAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    }
                } else {
                    showEmptyLayout(true);
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<ArrayList<Cupon>> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                Fn.Companion.showError(BusquedaActivity.this, getString(R.string.error_connection));
                showEmptyLayout(true);
                dialog.dismiss();
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Add the whole activity code to your question not as a link.

Comment: Please, share your activity code. Make sure you are not add itens again on your RV when you go back to your activity.

You should "update" your RV only when you first create the activity or when your service tells you to do it

Comment: The link is an image of the all activity, not the activity code Hasan.

Comment: Felipe, when I go back to the recyclerView activity, I remove all the items of the arrayList y set de adapter in null, after that, call the service and get the response en set to the arrayList y after that to the adapter.

Comment: I added the activity code on the post :).

Comment: Did you get a solution?>

Comment: @dfmarulanda It seems to be a code problem with the context inside the adapter. This is why the performance goes down.

Answer (score 0):

```
Picasso.get()
                    .load(url)
                    .error(R.drawable.mini_map)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.mini_map)
                    .centerInside()
                    .resize(400,200)
                    .into(postHolder.i_image);
```

solved this problem. this problems occurs when trying to render big sized images with Glide.